# POSTing a FormAPI form to another path?

Tags: 7, redirection, forms

I have a simple form, presenting an "Order this" button. That form is placed on a node. When people press that button, I want to start an ordering-workflow.

Currently the Drupal-way seems to be:

- Add form to node on `node/123`,
- User clicks form-submit, POST goes to `node/123`.
- `hook_form_submit()` gets fired, receives POSTed values trough form API.
- In that function, the POSTed-data is stored in a Session; then a drupal_goto() sends redirect-header to `/shop/checkout`, user GETs `/shop/checkout`.
- Code building the `/shop/checkout` page must retrieve information from Session to build the checkout-workflow.

How can I simply send the POST to `/shop/checkout` and present my HTML there, based on the POST, instead of all the intermediate goto and session-spaggetti?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to simply set `$form['#action']` to whatever URL you want to POST to.

Like this:

```
//....
$form = array(
  //..build the FAPI array
);
$form['#action'] = "shop/checkout";
return $form
```

In the place where you build the form. And the POST is sent to "shop/checkout".